# Permission denied using ecryptfs-setup-private as root

Tags: permissions, ecryptfs

If i create an encrypted home directory for a non-root user as root user, I mean:

```
ecryptfs-setup-private -u kok
```

After that, when kok login it fails to mount:

> Failed to detect wrapped passphrase version: Permission denied

The problem is easy fixed doing `chown -R kok /home/kok`

But I wonder if this is the expected behaviour of ecryptfs-utils.